# How can I take into consideration the object itself when calculating a hash for an object in Java?

Tags: java, object, hashmap, hashset, hashcode

I was working on some algorithmic problems when I got to this and it seemed interesting to me. If I have two lists (so two different objects), with the same values, the hashcode is the same. After some reading, I understand that this is how it should behave. For example:

```
        List<String> lst1 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("str1", "str2"));
        List<String> lst2 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("str1", "str2"));
        System.out.println(lst1.hashCode() + " " + lst2.hashCode());
        ...........
        Result: 2640541 2640541
```

My purpose would be to differentiate between lst1 and lst2 in a list for example.

Is there a structure (like a HashSet for example) that takes into consideration the actual object and not only the values inside the object when calculating the hashcode for something?

Comment: What do you mean by the `actual object`

Comment: The memory address of the object.

Comment: You can use `System.identityHashCode(lst1)`and `System.identityHashCode(lst2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use java's [java.util.IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), or [guava's identity hash set](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newIdentityHashSet--).

The hashes of the two lists [must be equal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), because the objects are equal. But the identity map and set above are based on the identity of the list objects, not their hash.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have two lists (so two different objects), with the same values, the hashcode is the same. After some reading, I understand that this is how it should behave.

Yes, this is part of the specification of `java.util.List`.

> Is there a structure (like a HashSet for example) that takes into consideration the actual object and not only the values inside the object when calculating the hashcode for something?
>
> My purpose would be to differentiate between lst1 and lst2 in a list for example

It is unclear what "in a list" means here.  For example, `Collection.contains()` and `List.equals()` are defined in terms or members' `equals()` methods, and likewise the behavior of `List.remove(Object)`.  Although distinct objects, your two `List`s will compare equal to each other, so those methods will not distinguish between them, neither directly nor as members of another list.  You can always compare them for reference equality (`==`), however, to determine that they are not the same object despite being `equals()` each other.

As far as a collection that takes members' object identity into account, you could consider [`java.util.IdentityHashMap`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html).  Two such maps having keys and associated values that are pairwise `equals()` each other but not identical will not compare `equals()` to each other.  Such sets will typically have different hash codes than each other, though that cannot be guaranteed.  Note well, however, the warnings throughout the documentation of `IdentityHashMap` that although it implements the `Map` API, many of the behavioral details are inconsistent with the requirements of that interface.

---

Note also that

- most of the above is relevant only for collections whose members are of a type that overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()`.  The implementations of or inherited from `Object` differentiate between objects on a reference-equality basis, so the ordinary collections classes have no surprises for you there.
- identical string literals are not required to represent distinct objects, so the `lst1` and `lst2` in your example  code may in fact contain identical elements, in the reference equality sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not generally in collections, because you generally want two collections with all the same items to be equal (which is why they implement it like this-  equals will return true and the hash codes are the same).

You can subclass a list and have it not do that, it would just not be widely useful and would cause a lot of confusion if other programmers read your code.  In that case, you'd just want equals to return the result of == and hashCode to return the integer value of the reference (the same thing that Object.equals does).